# What would be the best way to load data from the internet into ios app?

Tags: ios

i am looking at making an app for a cinema chain. i have experience in objective c but have not done may for loading data from the internet.

what i was asking is what would be the best way to load data into the app from the internet. the data will be stuff like images and names and times for the movies?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The best way is JSON. For movies you can use http://www.omdbapi.com/. Is an unofficial api for IMDB.

Comment: how would i then use the json data in my app?

Answer (score 0):

The JSON response from the [api](http://www.omdbapi.com/) can be consumed using `NSURLConnection` you can check apple's [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html) or you can simply use [RestKit](http://restkit.org/).

Comment: could i write a php application that could turn myslq querry result into json then use that json?

Comment: Yes. It doesn't matter as long as you get a JSON response.